how to list the terms from different equations knowing their factors in sympy?
I have equations with different factors and coefficients coming from a hierarchical collect operation. I search to list the terms knowing one factor.
Example:
import sympy
a, b, i, j, k = sympy.symbols('a b i j k')
# i j k are factors I collected equations

eq1 = b + i*(4*b + k*(-2*b**2 - 8*b*a - 8*a**2 + 8*a) - 2) + j*(-4*b + k*(2*b**2 + 8*b*a + 8*a**2 - 8*a) + 2) + k*(-0.5*b**2 - 2*b*a - 2*a**2 + 2*a)
eq2 = a + i*(-2*b + k*(b**2 + 4*b*a + 4*a**2 - 4*a) + 1.0) + j*(b - 2*a + k*(-b**2 - 4*b*a - 4*a**2 + 4*a)) + k*(0.25*b**2 + b*a + a**2 - a)

# my very naive approach (doesn't work for j and k, as j coefficient is function of k
dic = {}
a1 = str(eq1)
b1 = a1.split('+ i*')
dic['none'] = b1[0]
c1 = b1[-1].split('+ j*')
dic[i] = c1[0]

coef1 = sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr(dic[i])
print(dic)
print(coef1)

I want to obtain these kind of coefficient listing, How to automatize this process using sympy?
dic1 = ['none': b, i:(4*b + k*(-2*b**2 - 8*b*a - 8*a**2 + 8*a) - 2) , j:(-4*b + k*(2*b**2 + 8*b*a + 8*a**2 - 8*a) + 2) , k:(-0.5*b**2 - 2*b*a - 2*a**2 + 2*a)]
dic2 = ['none': a, i:(-2*b + k*(b**2 + 4*b*a + 4*a**2 - 4*a) + 1.0) , j: (b - 2*a + k*(-b**2 - 4*b*a - 4*a**2 + 4*a))  , k:(0.25*b**2 + b*a + a**2 - a) ]

The difficulty comes from the fact that I may have coefficient of i that are function of k or j, and of j function of k. The idea is to get a matrix expression and make some operation on these coefficients from different equations.
I tried on a naive way to convert into string and split equations, but it doesn't work for coefficient that are function of the other terms.
